# Dependency check when scripts are triggered in background bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a below code block in `bash` script. In this block of code I am triggering scripts in parallel and storing the `process id` of that scripts.

The script names are in a file called `session_details.txt` file.

Contents of the file are below

```
s01_test_abc
s02_run_cde
s02_skip_xyz
s03_failed_123
s03_success_999
s04_done_111
```

Bash script code

```
#!/bin/bash

wf_name=$1

# Create logs directory if not exists for that workflow
mkdir -p logs/${wf_name}

# Create run_share directory if not exists for that workflow
mkdir -p run_share/${wf_name}

# Date on which the workflow is running
run_date=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')
run_time=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')

# directory where current run status files are stored
share_dir=run_share/${wf_name}

# directory where current run logs are stored
logs_dir=logs/${wf_name}/${run_date}
number_of_jobs=0

PID_FILE=${logs_dir}/session_pid.txt
if [ -f ${PID_FILE} ]; then
  rm ${PID_FILE}
fi

## parallel call #####

while read session; do
   echo "processing started for ${session}"
   session_name=$(echo ${session%% })

    start_status_file=${share_dir}/${session_name}_start_${run_date}.txt
    end_status_file=${share_dir}/${session_name}_end_${run_date}.txt


    if [ -f ${start_status_file} ] & [ -f ${end_status_file} ] ; then
        echo "session --> ${session_name} has completed run for ${run_date}"
    elif [ -f ${start_status_file} ] ; then
        echo "Session --> ${session_name} has failed run for ${run_date} so restarting the failed job"
        sh ${wf_name}/${session_name}.sh ${wf_name} ${session_name} ${share_dir} ${run_date} ${logs_dir} > ${logs_dir}/${session_name}.log 2>&1 &
    else
        echo "Session --> ${session_name} has not run for ${run_date} so triggering new run"
        sh ${wf_name}/${session_name}.sh ${wf_name} ${session_name} ${share_dir} ${run_date} ${logs_dir} > ${logs_dir}/${session_name}.log 2>&1 &
    fi

   #sh ${wf_name}/${session_name}.sh ${wf_name} > ${logs_dir}/$session_name.log 2>&1 &
    pid=$!
    echo "${pid}-${session_name}" >> ${PID_FILE}
    echo "----------------"
    if [ ${number_of_jobs} -eq 0 ] ; then
        pid_list=${pid}
    else
        pid_list="${pid_list},${pid}"
    fi
    echo "PID list - ${pid_list}"
    number_of_jobs=$((number_of_jobs + 1))
    echo "${number_of_jobs} job(s) submitted so far"
   echo "done"
done < ${wf_name}/session_details.txt


## wait for parallel jobs completion

PID_OUT_FILE=${logs_dir}/session_pid_out.txt
if [ -f ${PID_OUT_FILE} ]; then
  rm ${PID_OUT_FILE}
fi

while read p; do
   pid=$(echo ${p} | cut -d'-' -f1)
   session_id=$(echo ${p} | cut -d'-' -f2)
   wait ${pid}
   echo $?"-"${p} >> ${PID_OUT_FILE}
done < ${PID_FILE}

## verify the pids completion status
while read res; do
   pidres=$(echo ${res} | cut -d'-' -f1)
   sess_id=$(echo ${res} | cut -d'-' -f3)
   if [ ${pidres} -ne 0 ]; then
      status_msg="FAILED"
      echo "job failed for session -${sess_id} failed"
   else
      echo "job for ${sess_id} Completed"
      status_msg="SUCCESS"
   fi
done < ${PID_OUT_FILE}

## fail the script if any parallel run job failed.
while read res; do
   pidres=$(echo ${res} | cut -d'-' -f1)
   sess_id=$(echo ${res} | cut -d'-' -f3)
   if [ ${pidres} -ne 0 ]; then
      exit -1
   fi
done < ${PID_OUT_FILE}
```

The code is working fine. I am achieving my result.

Now what I want to do is I want to trigger see how can I replicate this code when there is script level dependency.

For example.

```
Run the below script first 
s01_test_abc 

Then run below two in parallel after s01_test_abc is success if failed then exit the whole script
s02_run_cde
s02_skip_xyz

Then run below two scripts after above two parallel scripts are success if any one failed then exit the whole script
s03_failed_123
s03_success_999

Then run below script after above two parallel scripts are success if any one failed then exit the whole script
s04_done_111
```

How can I achieve that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to figure out how you're going to represent the dependencies you've described. If all of your commands are simple shell scripts that take no parameters, then an easy solution is to decide that each line of your input file represents a parallel set of commands that must complete successfully before the next step.  So instead of:

```
s01_test_abc
s02_run_cde
s02_skip_xyz
s03_failed_123
s03_success_999
s04_done_111
```

You would write:

```
s01_test_abc
s02_run_cde s02_skip_xyz
s03_failed_123 s03_success_999
s04_done_111
```

With this in place, your basic logic looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# read a line from the input file
while read set; do
    pids=()
    cmds=()

    # start the commands and store pids in the pids array
    for cmd in $set; do
        echo "starting $cmd"
        sh $cmd &
        pids+=($!)
        cmds+=($cmd)
    done

    echo "waiting for $set (${pids[@]})"

    failed=0

  # wait for each pid to finish, setting the `failed=1` if
  # anything fails.
  for i in $(seq ${#pids[*]}); do
        if ! wait ${pids[i]}; then
            echo "ERROR: command ${cmds[i]} (pid ${pids[i]}) failed" >&2
            failed=1
        fi
    done

  # if there were any failures, exit with an error.
    if [[ $failed = 1 ]]; then
        echo "ERROR: failure running $set" >&2
        exit 1
    fi
done < deps.txt
```

If I create a bunch of scripts that look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep $((RANDOM % 10))
exit $((RANDOM % 2))
```

And then run the above script, I will get output that might look like
this:

```
starting s01_test_abc
waiting for s01_test_abc (1085339)
starting s02_run_cde
starting s02_skip_xyz
waiting for s02_run_cde s02_skip_xyz (1085345 1085346)
ERROR: s02_run_cde (pid 1085345) failed
ERROR: failure running s02_run_cde s02_skip_xyz
```

Or like this:

```
starting s01_test_abc
waiting for s01_test_abc (1085782)
ERROR: s01_test_abc (pid 1085782) failed
ERROR: failure running s01_test_abc
```

Or this, if everything succeeds:

```
starting s01_test_abc
waiting for s01_test_abc (1086268)
starting s02_run_cde
starting s02_skip_xyz
waiting for s02_run_cde s02_skip_xyz (1086269 1086270)
starting s03_failed_123
starting s03_success_999
waiting for s03_failed_123 s03_success_999 (1086271 1086272)
starting s04_done_111
waiting for s04_done_111 (1086273)
```

---

But! You could also simply represent your dependencies as a `Makefile`...because `make` is, after all, a tool that can run things in parallel and can be told about the dependencies between different steps:

```
SCRIPTS = \
    s01_test_abc \
    s02_skip_xyz \
    s02_run_cde \
    s03_success_999 \
    s03_failed_123 \
    s04_done_111

FLAGS = $(SCRIPTS:=.done)

# This is a "pattern rule" that tells Make how to generate a file
# named <something>.done from an input file named <something>.
%.done: %
    @echo running $<
    @sh $< && touch $@ || { echo "$< failed!"; exit 1; }


all: $(FLAGS)

# here is where we express our dependencies
s02_skip_xyz.done s02_run_cde.done: s01_test_abc.done
s03_success_999.done s03_failed_123.done: s02_skip_xyz.done s02_run_cde.done
s04_done_111.done: s03_success_999.done s03_failed_123.done

clean:
    rm -f *.done
```

To run your scripts, just type:

```
make -j clean all
```

That gives you a much more structured format for representing your
dependencies, and it saves you from having to write a bunch of code
that effectively reproduces the same logic in a less robust fashion.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. all the scripts will take `parameters` as variables

Comment: Well, then you want option (b), the `Makefile`. That's a lot more flexible and it would be easy to call your scripts with arguments.

Comment: I have a small doubt in the above `bash` code in your answer if a failure happens you are printing out the `pids` and `set` of line from `file`. Is there a way to just print the `pid` and the `cmd` from `file` we passed if there is a failure

Comment: I've updated the shell script so that it does what I think you're asking (printing the name of the failed command instead of just the pid).

Comment: Yes that is what I wanted but now the code is not capturing any failures. It is completing the whole script instead of exiting at point of failure

Comment: It seems to work [when I run it](https://asciinema.org/a/BJUrvEESCZkSCKhiPtqcOXSOb).

Comment: I figured the issue out now it is working Thank you

Comment: @larsks Just curious to know if there is no `make` command available in the environment. How can we use your `bash` code to run scripts which take multiple `parameters/variables`

Comment: The easiest solution would probably be to change nothing in the script, and encapsulate any command line options in wrapper scripts of some sort and run those instead.